# Turn off syntax highlighting in minted?

Tags: minted, python, syntax-checker

How do I turn off syntax highlighting in minted?

Defining my DSL with a CFG and then a PEG; and the syntax highlighting is getting in the way.

Comment: Wow, looks like the `pycon` lexer does the trick…

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's a `text` lexer that highlights nothing.

Comment: Too bad [this is not listed on the pygments website](https://pygments.org/languages/), so I could not find it there… 

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and *G. Poore*'s answer was accepted long ago, however I leave this here in case it saves someone some time:

You could define the following command:

```
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\txtmint}[1]{\mintinline[fontsize=\scriptsize, bgcolor=Gray]{text}{#1}}
```

Which you can just use as: `\txtmint{some code without syntax highlighting}`.

Within the `[]` in the definition of the command, you can specify any options you want. With these settings you get something like this:

[image: minted]