# How to disable minted highlighting in tcolorbox's dispExample environment?

Tags: fonts, tcolorbox, minted, pgfkeys

I'm now making a documentation of a small LaTeX package with `documentation` library from the `tcolorbox` package, and having difficulty in printing sample codes without any syntax highlighting.

According to [G. Poore's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131894), we can set the language as `text` to turn off the coloring, which can be specified via [`/tcb/minted language` key](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf#subsection.15.5). Thus, I tried to redefine the corresponding value like the following MWE (the first two are just for comparison).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{listing engine=minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{minted language=text}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{dispExample}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{dispExample}
\tcbset{
  docexample/.add style={}{
    fontlower=\normalsize,
    minted language=text,
    documentation minted options={
      autogobble=true,
      fontsize=\small
    }
  }
}
\begin{dispExample}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{dispExample}
\end{document}
```

Typesetting this with `pdflatex -shell-escape` gave me

[image: output of the MWE]

As you can see, the option `minted language=text` seems to be invalid in the third box while other key-value settings (e.g., `fontlower=\normalsize`) works.
Also, `minted language=text` is valid in the normal `tcblisting` environment.

How can I `.add style` the `minted language` key to the `docexample` style? What am I doing wrong?

I could have directly asked this question at Prof. Thomas F. Sturm's GitHub repository, but I use TeX.SX expecting more people will have a look.

**Update:**

Thanks to @egreg's answer, I found that my issue lies in the combination of `tcolorbox` and <s>`newtxtt`</s> (after some investigation, the same behaviour was confirmed with other monospaced fonts).
Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{newtxtt}
\tcbset{
  listing engine=minted,
  docexample/.add style={}{
    fontlower=\normalsize,
    minted language=latex,
    documentation minted options={
      autogobble=true,
      fontsize=\small,
      style=bw,
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{dispExample}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{dispExample}
\end{document}
```

This gives control sequences in boldface, which I don't like, although `style=bw` is specified.

[image: output of the second MWE]

Monospaced fonts that reproduce this problem include

- Courier (`\usepackage{courier}`),
- DejaVu (`\usepackage{dejavu}`),
- Fira (`\usepackage{firamono}`),
- Incondolata (`\usepackage{zi4}`), and
- Source Code Pro (`\usepackage{sourcecodepro}`),

while Latin Modern and Droid don't trigger the problem.

**Yet Another Update**:

The second part of this question now has [its own thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366544/doccommand-environment-and-some-others-print-control-sequences-in-boldface-with).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the `documentation` library assumes all (minted) texts to be of `latex` language. Therefore, `minted language` has deliberately no effect on `dispExample` environments.

Nevertheless, I take it as a feature request to make this configurable in the same way as `documentation minted options`.

The following patch introduces a new option `documentation minted language` which will be integrated into `tcolorbox` version `4.03` and higher:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\tcbset{
  documentation minted language/.store in=\kvtcb@docminted@language,
  documentation minted language=latex,
}

\def\tcb@minted@doc@usetemplisting{%
  \tcb@minted@input@listing{\kvtcb@docmintoptions}{\kvtcb@docminted@language}{\kvtcb@tempfile}{\kvtcb@docmintstyle}%
}

\tcbset{listing engine=minted}

\makeatother

\begin{tcblisting}{minted language=text}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{dispExample}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{dispExample}

\tcbset{
  docexample/.add style={}{
    fontlower=\normalsize,
    documentation minted language=text,
    documentation minted options={
      autogobble=true,
      fontsize=\small
    }
  }
}

\begin{dispExample}
  \begin{equation}
    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
  \end{equation}
\end{dispExample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the patch works well also. Regarding the font weight problem, which still remains, I'll open another question with a reduced MWE later.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass `style=bw` to `pygmentize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  listing engine=minted,
  docexample/.add style={}{
    fontlower=\normalsize,
    minted language=latex, % <--------
    documentation minted options={
      autogobble=true,
      fontsize=\small,
      style=bw, % <-------
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{dispExample}
\begin{equation}
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation}
\end{dispExample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know the `style` key but it didn't give me a desired result neither. My actual case is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRGgV.png), where some control sequences are in boldface. This is why I next tried the `minted language`. That being said, your code works on my end as well. I'll update the question after investigating a _true_ cause and making a new MWE.

Comment: I updated the question.