# docCommand environment and some others print control sequences in boldface with certain fonts

Tags: fonts, tcolorbox, minted

This is a follow-up question to [the previous one of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345990/how-to-disable-minted-highlighting-in-tcolorboxs-dispexample-environment).

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
% \usepackage{newtxtt}
\begin{document}
\begin{docCommand}{foo}{}
  \verb|\foo|
\end{docCommand}
\end{document}
```

The result (with Computer Modern) is like the following and this is as intended:

[image: Output w/ CM]

If we uncomment the line `\usepackage{newtxtt}`, the red `\foo` gets bold while the black one remains regular weight.

[image: Output w/ newtxtt]

Font packages with which this issue can be confirmed are

- Courier (`\usepackage{courier}`),
- DejaVu (`\usepackage{dejavu}`),
- Fira (`\usepackage{FiraMono}`),
- Incondolata (`\usepackage{zi4}`), and
- Source Code Pro (`\usepackage{sourcecodepro}`).

I find it very weird that the font series used in the first argument of `docCommand` environment varies according to the font family. How come this happens?

Comment: Ulrike Fischer answered the question. I will add a new option `keywords bold` to the next `tcolorbox` version to switch off boldface, if needed.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I appreciate it if you consider that option deserves implementation as a package feature. Redefining `\tcb@Print@***`s is easy but provision of such interface would be much better IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font series is bold for all font families. But the typewriter font family of computer modern has no bold variant and so LaTeX falls back to the normal series. In the log you will find the message:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/cmtt/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 7.
```

Comment: You were some seconds faster than me :-) Indeed, the `docCommand` is intended to set the key words bold, but does not work for the original computer modern typewriter font.

Comment: To my shame, I didn't know the lack of boldface in CM while LM has font series `b`...

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Sorry but it was in the core a `fonts` question ;-). But here a tcolorbox for you: is there a better way to set the baseline measured from the top that this one: http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?77202-Vertikale-Ausrichtung-einer-tcolorbox-in-einer-enumerate-Umbegung&p=362624&viewfull=1#post362624