# tcolorbox dispExample in Beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, minted, tcblisting

I used the [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346016/35874) in beamer, but it doesn't work. How to handle it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `fragile` frame option if your frame contains something fragile like a lstlisting.

(and don't forget to compile with shell-escape enabled)

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{example-image-duck}}

\tcbset{
  boxrule=0pt,
  opacityfill=0,
  listing engine=minted,
  docexample/.add style={}{
    fontlower=\normalsize,
    minted language=latex, % <--------
    documentation minted options={
      autogobble=true,
      fontsize=\small,
      style=bw, % <-------
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{dispExample}
\begin{equation}
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp (-x^2) \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}
\end{equation}
\end{dispExample}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, I want to add boxrule=0pt and opacityfill=0 options.

Comment: @kalakay Yes? Both options work without problem

Comment: (although I'd be a bit careful with changing the opacity, this can sometimes cause unexpected problems. Unless you are using a background image, I'd just set the fill colour to be the same as the background canvas)

Comment: Well, it is. I use a background image. With the opacityfill=0 option, the result is not visible.

Comment: @kalakay I just updated my answer, works fine for me. Can you test with this code?

Comment: I use a black background. It's still not working.

Comment: @kalakay Can you make a minimal working example so that I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: (just checking: you did change the text colour to something non-black, didn't you?)

Comment: No. Look, I've edited it.

Comment: @kalakay Can you add your code as text to your question, not as image?

Comment: Solved! I used text colour for the right side. The options are boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,lower separated=false,opacityfill=0,coltext=white. Thank you, @samcarter.